# To find all the convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb Z_+\times \mathbb Z_+$, where $\mathbb Z_+=\{0,1,2,...\}$ and $\tau=\mathcal P(X\setminus\{0,0\})\cup \{G\subset X:(0,0)\in G, \{m\in \mathbb Z_+:\{n\in \mathbb Z_+:(m,n)\notin G\}$ is infinite$\}$is finite$\}$.

I have shown that $\tau$ is a topology. Now I want to find all convergent sequences in $(X,\tau)$. I believe eventually constant sequences are only sequences which can converge to $(m,n)\ne (0,0)$. But what are the sequences converge to $(0,0)$? I couldn't find. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The neighbourhoods of $(0,0)$ are the sets $V$ containing $(0,0)$ and with the property that for almost all $m$, the section $V_m = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ : (m,n) \in V\}$ contains almost all $n$.

A particularly simple family of neighbourhoods is

$$R_{m,n} = \{(0,0)\} \cup [m,\infty)\times [n,\infty).$$

So if a sequence in $X' := X\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ converges to $(0,0)$, one must necessarily have that both components individually converge (diverge?) to $\infty$. Thus if we have a candidate sequence in $X'$ for convergence to $(0,0)$, we can extract a subsequence that is strictly monotonic in both components. But such a sequence cannot converge to $(0,0)$, since another family of neighbourhoods of $(0,0)$ is given by

$$S(s,M) = \bigcup_{m=M}^\infty \{m\}\times [s_m,\infty)$$

where $M \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and $s$ is an arbitrary sequence in $\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Given two strictly monotonic sequences $(m_k)$ and $(n_k)$, let

$$s_m = n_{m_k} + 1\quad\text{if } m_{k-1} < m \leqslant m_k,$$

with $m_{-1} = -1$ for the start.

Then $S(s,0)$ is a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ that contains no term of the sequence $p_k = (m_k,n_k)$.

So the only sequences in $X$ converging to $(0,0)$ are the eventually constant ones.